# EL & spring tags not being parsed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, el

I'm setting up a new project, but for some reason my tags like ${name} or  are not being processed. Even ${2+2} is not being processed.
I've looked over the configuration but I just can't seem to spot what's wrong.

Update: updating the web.xml resolved the EL tags not being processed, but the form tags still aren't being parsed.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <form:form path="helloBean" method="post">      
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name"/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </form:form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pom snipped to the spring dependencies dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: And the rendered HTML shows the tags, un-evaluated, but there's no errors in the build or log?

Comment: Indeed, if I view the source I see: `<form id="command" path="helloBean" method="post">`. No errors either in my command prompt. (using mvn tomcat:run)

Comment: Er, that's what should be rendered, and that's not the same as your JSP source. I no longer understand what the problem is. Please update the question to reflect the files I asked for in my comment. You're also using plain HTML tags for the input elements, is that what you intended?

Comment: Ah, thought that would get parsed so it was no longer visible. The code in my question is from the .jsp file. the one in my comment is from the rendered source. The issue is that when I put <form:input path="name"/> within the <form> tags I get: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute while I put the formAttribute to helloBean.

Comment: Fudge, just noticed I put path instead of modelAttribute on the form tag. Now I feel retarded...

Comment: Oh, yeah, that'd do it. It won't be rendered to be *nothing*; there still needs to be an HTML form so there's something to submit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `web.xml` to a version that supports EL (2.5+ XSD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

</web-app>
```

Comment: I modified it to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">` and whilst the EL is now parsed, the form tags still aren't handled.Any idea why?

Comment: @JackNickels Did you include the taglib directive(s) for the tags you're using?

Comment: @JackNickels You'll need to provide more details then; anything in the logs? Also, update your question to reflect the current code, add the JSP, remove the context and pom.